# authenticate_user! method not working after Api versioning rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise, rails-api

I use rails as backend for mobile app. I tried including versions for the Api. I use devise for authentication and now the authenticate_user! method is not working and it shows me the error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate_user!' for
#<Api::V1::CategoryController:0x00000103b95088>)
```

I do not know where i am doing wrong. please help me resolve this problem. Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

```
module Api
    module V1
class CategoryController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution by now?

Comment: Sorry. Still i could not find the solution and so left it undone. If you find something someday please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after versioning my API. It seems that Devise, after adding namespaces, Devise changes the **authenticate_user!** method to **authenticate_api_v1_user!** and also **current_user** to **current_api_v1_user**. That happens if you are namespacing like this:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    devise_for :users do
      resources :sessions, defaults: {format: :json}
   end
  end
end
```

In order to solve the issue, you have to define devise_for first, before the namespacing. That way you will be able to access authenticate_user and current_user.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "api/v1/sessions" }
devise_scope :user do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :sessions, defaults: {format: :json}
    end
  end
end
resources :users
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I found this while trying to use devise within the versionist gem. Here is a gist of my solution for keeping the devise routes within the versionist scope block: 
 https://gist.github.com/Genkilabs/587fab4214798c87c3aa97bb06280f43

Answer (score 0):

I think, `authenticate_user!` added to `ApplicationController`.

If your Api controller inherit from another controller (not `ApplicationController`), u need to include this helper to your Api controller manually.

Comment: `https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/4681f81ce6b643cd55d7404500ee02ab18bab5df/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L46-L49`
Devise used for `User` model?

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L48-L51